# Apache. View only access on a directory

Tags: apache, directory

Within apache can I restrict users to listing the contents of a directory or is it true to say that once a user has been allowed access there is nothing to restrict them from downloading the content?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory "c:/[your path]">

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all

#Options Indexes

    <LimitExcept ALL>
         require user [your user]
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

Without the `Option Indexes` in the file *.conf, the user can't listing the content of the directory. They steal can access to a ressource of the file.

I think it was what you asking for!